# Sub getting "Expected: =" after adding variable

Tags: vba

I am writing a sub to do some stuff and it is working great with 1 variable. When I try to add a second it throws an error saying that it is expecting an =.

**Works Fine:**

Call Sub

```
makeUniqueID (compare2)
```

Create Sub

```
Sub makeUniqueID(sheet As String)
 'does some stuff
End Sub
```

**Throws Error**

Call Sub

```
makeUniqueID(compare2 , compare1)
```

Create Sub

```
Sub makeUniqueID(sheet As String, title As String)
  'Does some Stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the parentheses when calling a Sub:

```
makeUniqueID compare2, compare1
```

Alternatively, as @niallmcfc points out, you can call a sub like this:

```
Call makeUniqueID(compare2, compare1)
```

But this `Call` notation adds unnecessary clutter and has fallen out of favour. [Documentation on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcx04ck5%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You only really need parentheses when calling a function, e.g.:

```
result = myFun(var1, var2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting "Call" in front of the sub when you call it-

```
Call makeUniqueID(compare2, compare1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Jean 's answer:

Calling a `Sub` without `Call` and enclosing a parameter in `()` actually changes the behaviour of the `Sub`

By default `Parameters` are called `ByRef`, so

```
Sub makeUniqueID(sheet As String)
```

Is the same as

```
Sub makeUniqueID(ByRef sheet As String)
```

Calling a `Sub` it like this:

```
makeUniqueID (compare2)
```

**overrides the reference type**, and makes it a `ByVal` call.

The bottom line is saying `makeUniqueID (compare2)` "Works Fine" is not quite true.

This only matters when you intend the `Sub` to modify the source parameter passed to it.